# Where is XOR EAX, 2 (and load/store/pointer-increment) commonly used?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I am trying to learn assembly lately.
A friend of mine showed me the following instructions :

```
mov EAX, [EDX]
xor EAX, 2
mov [EBX], EAX
inc EDX
inc EBX
```

To which I replied,

```
1. Value at `edx` address is loaded in `eax`
2. Value in `eax` is XORed by 2 
3. Value in `eax` is stored back in memory address mentioned in `ebx`
Increment edx and ebx.
```

Is my explanation correct ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Secondly he asked, where is this used the most ?

Is this some kind of regular code routine instructions? Can anyone please help me where is this used the most ?

Please pardon my understanding/mistakes. I am very new to assembly.

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct. It could be used in some simple form of encryption, xoring a source buffer into a destination. You'd also need a loop of course.

Comment: Note that this loads and stores 4 bytes at a time. However, the `inc` instructions only increment both pointers by one each, not 4. (The upper 3 bytes in the `eax` register are not altered by the `xor` instruction though.)

Comment: @ecm - yes, I thought the same. Can we just increment register values randomly ? Won't it create invalid memory location error ?

Comment: @v1h5: Incrementing a pointer and then accessing memory at the pointer's new address can be a valid operation, eg to iterate through a buffer that is larger than 1 byte. However, if you increment past the end of a buffer then loading from or storing to that address can be invalid too. For example, these accesses could silently access other buffers or variables. Or they could result in a segmentation fault if the accesses are to an unmapped page.

Comment: @ecm - Got it. May be then this concept leads to buffer overflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pointlessly inefficient and weird (with overlapping 4-byte loads/stores if this is in a loop), so I doubt you'd find it anywhere, but yes you've correctly described what it does.

It's also not normal to copy a buffer and just flip the 2nd bit of every byte (assuming EDX and EBX point to non-overlapping buffers).

But if you were going to do that, you'd either go a byte at a time with `movzx eax, byte [edx]` loads and `mov [ebx], al` stores, or you'd `add ebx,4`/`add edx,4` so you could `xor eax, 0x02020202`.  (Or better use SSE1 or SSE2 to copy and XOR 16 bytes at a time.)

With a more complicated XOR constant, this gets used to lightly obfuscate strings or other data from simple low-effort reverse engineering like `strings ./a.out` to find contiguous ASCII bytes in an executable.

See for example [glibc `memfrob(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memfrob.3.html) which XORs with `42` (`0x2a`), in-place instead of copying.  As you can tell from the constant which doesn't have its high bit set (so most printable ASCII characters stay printable ASCII), this function is at least half a joke.  People will still find your strings, they're just not immediately readable.

Comment: That's a nice explanation (though a bit high level for a beginner like me. I am trying to grasp :D ) but I am happy that my initial understanding is correct. 
Thank you for explaining.